# Top level nav item not set as a parent of a sublevel item with posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a theme, but having an issue with making sure that a top level nav element is set as the current parent when showing a post in a blog feed/archive. Here is an example:

- About

  - News Feed

When on the News Feed page, the About list element includes the classes "current_page_parent", "current_page_ancestor", and "current-menu-ancestor" among its classes. However, once I'm on a news post, the About list element does not show any of the classes, although the News Feed list element does have "current_page_parent".

Any ideas how to get this to work? I've worked with the Walker_Nav_Menu class before, but for the life of me I can't think of a way to make sure the level 1 nav element sees that it's a parent of a menu item with a post.